# jQuery Isotope plugin working on local but not on live server

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm working on a website that relies a lot on a masonry layout with filtering options, so I worked with [isotope from metafizzy], it's working fine on my local server, but it's not working on the live server even though the sites are identical. 
Both the filtering and the masonry layout are not working.

Here is a link to see the live site where the problem occurs:
[link to the portfolio page](http://mmarauder.com/nbav-website/travaux.html)
you can see the same issue on the Journal page on the same site.

For now, it's a static site, but it's going to be a WordPress theme. So I would really appreciate some help to understand what I'm missing here.

On the same topic, does anyone know a good plugin that does exactly what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what was going on. As I said in my original post, the files and paths are correct. I'm basically cloning a local site via SFTP with sublime text to a live server. So if everything is fine on the local site, there is no reason for it to be wrong on the live server.

I could see that the console was giving me an error, but after verifying the files and paths several times, I couldn't find an error. So I investigated a bit on the specific type of message: Error 403. And I found that this error can show up for the following reasons:

- Empty httpdocs directory, that was clearly not the case;
- No index page, that was not the problem either;
- Permissions and ownership errors, this one I didn't know much about, so I checked the permissions on the folders and files on the server and that was the issue. The isotope.pkged.min.js didn't have permissions for: Read and Execute. The solution was simple enough, changing the files permissions on the server.

In case someone encounters the same type of problem, I hope this little story will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that isotope.pkged.min.js is not being loaded. The link in your script is either incorrect or you have not uploaded the file to the js folder on your server.

Comment: That's the thing, the link is correct and the script is in the proper folder. It seems to be more related to a file permission problem (error 403). But I don't know what to do to solve it.

Comment: The Developer console shows that the link is not correct or the file is not present. The easy thing to do is upload the file again or copy the isotope.js code and paste it in the packery-mode.pkgd.min.js file, before the packery code.